# layout doesn't always load

Tags: android

I redesigned my project by simplifying the code programming. i placed all the images that are static through the xml layout.

i get only 2 results when i run the program.

1) running with no problems

[image]

2) running with problems

[image]

i get the following error:

```
Connected to process 10651 on device 4.7_WXGA_API_22 [emulator-5554]
I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

I believe the problem lies somewhere in this inner class, i think?!

```
 private class MatchCardGame{

    private Game mMatchGame;

    private List<Drawable> revealImagesOfCards;
    private List<Integer> revealCards;
    private Drawable hiddenCard;
    private List<Integer> cardPoints;
    private List< Boolean> isHidden;

    public MatchCardGame(int numOfCards){

        mMatchGame = new Game(numOfCards);
        revealImagesOfCards = new ArrayList<>();
        revealCards = new ArrayList<>();
        cardPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        isHidden = new ArrayList<>();

        setCoverCard();

        for(int i = 1; i <= numOfCards; i++)
            setMatchImageCard(i);

    }
    public void setMatchImageCard( int cardLoc){

        int drawableLoc =  mMatchGame.findImageOfCard(cardLoc);
       Drawable drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), drawableLoc, null);
        Integer revealCard = mMatchGame.findContentsOfCard(cardLoc);

        revealImagesOfCards.add(drawable);
        revealCards.add(revealCard);
        cardPoints.add(Integer.valueOf(20));
        Boolean hideCard = true;
        isHidden.add(hideCard);

    }
    private void setCoverCard(){
        hiddenCard = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.black_card, null);
    }

    public Drawable getImage(int loc, boolean statReveal){
        loc--;
        if(!statReveal){
            Boolean hideCard = isHidden.get(loc);
            hideCard = true;
            return hiddenCard;
        }
        else {
            Boolean hideCard = isHidden.get(loc);
            hideCard = false;
            return revealImagesOfCards.get(loc);
        }



    }

    public boolean getHiddenStat(int loc){
        loc--;
        Boolean hideCard = isHidden.get(loc);
        return  hideCard;
    }

    public boolean compareCards(int loc1, int loc2){
        loc1--;
        loc2--;

        Integer card1 = revealCards.get(loc1);
        Integer card2 = revealCards.get(loc2);
        Integer cardPts1 = cardPoints.get(loc1);
        Integer cardPts2 = cardPoints.get(loc2);


        if(card1 == card2){

            int num = Integer.valueOf( scoreText.getText().toString());

            Log.i("TAGG","Score Points: " + (cardPts1 + cardPts2));
            new AdjustScore().execute(Integer.valueOf(cardPts1 + cardPts2));


            return true;
        }

        else{


            cardPts1 -= 5;
            cardPts2 -= 5;


            if(cardPts1 < 0)
                cardPts1 = 0;

            if(cardPts2 < 0)
                cardPts2 = 0;

            cardPoints.set(loc1, cardPts1);
            cardPoints.set(loc2,cardPts2);

            return false;
        }


    }

    private class AdjustScore extends AsyncTask<Integer,Integer,Void>{

        private TextView scoreText;
        private int currentScore;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            scoreText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_txt);
            currentScore = Integer.valueOf( scoreText.getText().toString());
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
          final  int num = integers[0];

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

            for (int x = 1; x <= num; x++){


                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(20);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                      publishProgress(Integer.valueOf(currentScore + x));
                    }


            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();

        return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            Message msg = scoreHandler.obtainMessage();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("myPoints",String.valueOf(values[0]));



            msg.setData(bundle);
            scoreHandler.sendMessage(msg);

        }
    }


}
```

I call this in onCreate of activity

```
private MatchCardGame myGame;
private List<Integer> selectCards;
private TextView scoreText;

private Handler scoreHandler = new Handler(){

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
        String stat1 = bundle.getString("myPoints");

        int num = Integer.valueOf(stat1);


        scoreText.setText(String.valueOf(num));


    }


};
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_game);

    myGame = new MatchCardGame(12);
}
```

I have another inner class derived from AsynTask.
it is mainly used to setup the card views and set clicklisteners on imageviews. but i don't think it is the problem.

Comment: You can try glide library which loads images efficiently. [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/)  might help

Comment: You should profile how long its taking to decode your images. Do some performance evaluation from your side to better understand how your code is functioning. Also consider looking at what your app is doing in the separate async tasks by using logs. Also most games actually post a splash screen while content is being loaded to make sure content is ready and available. However; you should try to optimize from your side and understand your application's behavior.

Comment: @AkshayBhat'AB'  This is nothing Glide or any other image library can fix.  He has local images and is loading them on a task-  that always has the potential for a race condition.

Answer (score 2):

First off, those aren't errors.  They're the garbage collector.  That's perfectly normal, and shouldn't give you any concern unless you have a performance issue at the same time.  Doing something in code rather than in xml to avoid those is unnecessary, and will work or not based on pure luck of when the garbage collector is needed.

Secondly, you're loading all your images in an AsyncTask.  Sometimes thats good (it stops you from pausing the main thread to load images), but if you don't have a default image in place, then until that task is done it won't actually be able to display any images.  So you have a race condition between drawing and the task finishing.

Solution:  do it in xml, or put up a loading screen.  I suggest the first, because your task isn't actually doing anything useful if the images are static images from the app-  those were loaded when the app launched.

Comment: out of curiosity, what is a loading screen and how do i put it up. is it done through xml, onCreate(), constructor, or some other overridden method.

Comment: A loading screen is better known as a Splash Activity. It's basically an intro screen as you might have seen in many applications, mainly they are composed by the application name in full screen, where content is loaded and most tasks are initially performed, so that the user doesn't have to wait for the data to load on an empty screen.